# when fetching firestore database "itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length" is not working anymore. does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

this is the code:...............

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Practice Firebase"),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Animals").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: const CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data?.documents.length, 
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: snapshot.data.documents[index]["name"],
                      );
                    });
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'documents', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'

Comment: Try `docs` instead of `documents`.

Comment: I also used docs but the same problem

Comment: You also have to manage the situation when the stream is waiting for completion, like `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)`, in this case you also have to return a progress indicator. Set a breakpoint and check what's in `snapshot.data`.

Comment: Can you show me an Example? I Have Printed the `snapshot.body`. I Found this:

`[Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the code skeleton below (here I have an own class `MyAnimal` so I can use members instead of map):

```
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Animals')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        // handle error
        return const Text('Error');
      }

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        // return progress indicator widget
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      // here you should get the streamed documents like:
      // snapshot.data!.docs

      // so to build a ListView for example:

      return ListView(
        children:
            snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          final animal = document.data() as MyAnimal;
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(animal.name!),
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me. So basically you need to give the `snapshot` the datatype of `AsyncSnapshot`since `.docs`cannot be called on an Object type.

```
StreamBuilder(
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
```

Answer (score 0):

just declare the dataType of builder arguments..i mean,
builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapShot)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkzLN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well actually, if you do this - you can access docs and length ...

builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot LessThanSign QuerySnapshot GreaterThanSign streamSnapShot){}